# Convert list to dictionary with value as comma-separated string

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I need to convert a list into a dictionary based on key. I have a list below with `Id`, `Name`, and so on:

```
List<MyData> lst = new List<MyData>();

MyData objMyData = new MyData();
MyData objMyData1 = new MyData();
MyData objMyData2 = new MyData();
objMyData.Id = 1;
objMyData.Name = "Test";
lst.Add(objMyData);
objMyData1.Id = 2;
objMyData1.Name = "Test2";
lst.Add(objMyData1);
objMyData2.Id = 1;
objMyData2.Name = "Test3";
lst.Add(objMyData2);
```

As per my requirement, I need to create a dictionary object from it in this format.

```
Dictionary<int, string>
```

Where the key is `Id` and the value is `Name` with comma-separated. iIt should look like:

```
Dictionary<1, "Test, test3">
Dictionary<2, "Test2">
```

I'm trying the below code, but stuck.

```
var dict = lst.ToLookup(x => x.Id)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=>x.ToList());
```

Here instead of `x.ToList()`, I require to get `list.name` with comma-separated based on key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ToList()` will return the grouped list of `MyData`.

You should select the `Name` and combine it into a string.

```cs
var dict = lst.ToLookup(x => x.Id)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => String.Join(", ", x.Select(y => y.Name)));
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6CgDi)

Comment: Thank @Yong, That works!. I was actually trying the same thing but getting syntax error. I actually use string.join inside y.name, that didnt work. anyway thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ` to group the items by their ID and then concatenate the names accordingly.

```
var dict = lst
  .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Join(", ", g.Select(item => item.Name)));
```

Comment: `GroupBy` can be a better approach (no extra materialization) than `ToLookup`, +1